# Policy on labelling questions as "updated"

Tags: discussion, etiquette

The FAQ encourages editing one's own question "to provide status and progress updates. [...] This will naturally bump your question". However, what is our stance on additionally labelling the edited question as "UPDATED", as has been done in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9095/biblatex-customization-author-name-format-defined-by-hyphenation-localization) case? Personally, I regard such labelling as somewhat cluttering up the site, and I would undo the changes to the question title either immediately or at least as soon as an answer has been acccepted.

Comment: Agreed, "UPDATED" in the _title_ should be discouraged.

Comment: Also leave a comment for the op when you change it, so that it won't be repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed the label "UPDATED" from the respective question and left a comment explaining my motives. (Hopefully, the comment was somewhat tongue-in-cheek.)